# Make [global-warming] a synonym of [climate-change]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[climate-change](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate-change) [global-warming](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/global-warming)

I'm not sure we need two different tags. Most everyone uses the verbiage `climate change` and not `global warming` nowadays (at least in politics). I'm not sure there's a good case for having separate tags for political discussion purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done. All questions tagged "global warming" should now be tagged "climate change".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but: The lemma on Wikipedia is [Global warming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_warming):

> **Global warming** is the long-term rise in the average temperature of the
>   Earth's climate system. It is a major aspect of **climate change** and has
>   been demonstrated by direct temperature measurements and by
>   measurements of various effects of the warming. Global warming and
>   climate change are often used interchangeably. But, more
>   accurately, global warming is the mainly human-caused increase in
>   global surface temperatures and its projected continuation, while
>   climate change includes both global warming and its effects, such as
>   changes in precipitation.

I consider *climate change* an **euphemism**.

So it should be the other way: Make *climate change* a synonym of *global warming*.

But the consensus on SE seems to be that *climate change* should be the lemma:  [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/tags/climate-change/synonyms), [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tags/climate-change/synonyms) and [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/climate-change/synonyms) do this. [Sustainable Living](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/global-warming) has [both](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate-change).

Comment: I would post this as a new question. My goal was a synonym, which is now done. We don't need two tags either way

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked more than two years ago, but I was just about to ask the exact same question when the "similar questions" box showed me this just before posting.

I think in politics and everyday discussion the two terms are synonyms. It only makes sense to distinguish between the two from a scientific viewpoint. At the moment we have 50 questions tagged with [climate-change](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate-change) and 14 questions tagged with [global-warming](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/global-warming) (5 questions have both tags), so I feel that global-warming should be merged into climate-change.

I can see [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tags/global-warming/synonyms) that someone already proposed climate-change as a synonym for global-warming, so exactly the other way around. This proposal doesn't seem to have any upvotes yet. I would downvote it and propose a synonym on climate-change, but I can't due to lack of reputation on the tags.

Answer (score -1):

[Climate change =/= global warming](https://www.climate.gov/news-features/climate-qa/whats-difference-between-global-warming-and-climate-change).

> Global warming refers only to the Earth’s rising surface temperature, while climate change includes warming and the “side effects” of warming—like melting glaciers, heavier rainstorms, or more frequent drought. Said another way, global warming is one symptom of the much larger problem of human-caused climate change.

Comment: While this can be scientifically true, this make no difference specific to Politics (and Politics.StackExchange). If we keep two separate tags, an arbitrary Q will either have both tags or none.

Comment: What are you proposing with this answer? That we keep both tags? Or that we should merge [tag:climate-change] in to [tag:global-warming] (rather than the reverse)?